# Как браузер воспроизводит видео с ютуба?

Tags: веб-программирование, google-chrome

Подскажите пожалуйста, а как браузер, к примеру Хром воспроизводит видео к примеру с ютуба ?

То есть через инструмент разработчика Хром я смотрю, как загружается видео, то есть оно через XHR буфера малыми порциями по ~500K приходят в формате mp4 или webm, но если этот отдельный буфер сохранить на диск и попробовать запустить стандартно плеер-проигрывателем, то он не запустится, так как формат не известен.

Как же тогда браузер это делает ?

Comment: Это кусочки одного файла, чтобы воспроизвелось, нужно их сперва собрать в единый файл

Comment: Ну и вообще гуглите про HLS и MPEG-DASH